# Are 3h 58m enough time to transfer flights in Atlanta (from Colombia to Germany)?

Tags: transit, short-connections, atlanta

I'm flying from Colombia to Munich with transfer in Atlanta. The transit time is 3h and 58m. The flight is on Sunday and Atlanta, indeed, is the airport with the heaviest passenger transit in the world. Is it reasonable to think that I will have sufficient time to change flights? Am I in high risk of losing the flight? Bear in mind that I will have to pass immigration with a tourist Visa (last time at JFK, I spent almost 2 hours doing the immigration row). I don't know the airport or if I will have to change terminals.

Comment: What airline(s) are you flying? Barring a terrible experience in immigration, 4 hours should be plenty of time to transfer.

Comment: Usually the international arrivals and departures will be in the same terminal. There is an International Terminal at ATL. If you were flying to somewhere in the US you would be more likely to change terminals, but Colombia to Germany probably will be in the same terminal.

Comment: You should also be able to look up the same flights from today's schedule and see what gates they used to get a better idea. Try a flight tracker website or phone app.

Comment: @NadjaCS international - International connections in US also require you to pass through immigration on arrival

Comment: @Akash - Yes indeed. But there was also a question about changing terminals. Immigration is going to be accessible from the international terminal. The international arrival and departure will most likely both be in the international terminal, but this can be confirmed by looking at past instances of the same flights.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst It doesn't really matter. Getting between terminals at ATL is very fast.

Comment: @NadjaCS Getting between terminals at ATL is very fast so, even if the asker needed to do that, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Atlanta is a very efficient airport.

They have a large immigration and customs area, which moves passengers through expeditiously. If your bags are checked through to Munich, then you simply drop that at recheck just outside customs, clear security and head to your gate.

If you are flying on different tickets or airlines, then you may have to recheck your bags.  The International check in is just outside F concourse, so doesn't take too long to reach it for check in.

All concourses are interconnected by a train which runs every five minutes or so.  But most International flights depart from E & F concourses which is where you will likely arrive.

4 hours should be ample plenty.